# have to click mysql workbench execute button twice

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Whenever I want to execute any query using MySQL-workbench,I have to click execute button twice. The first time I click the execute button, it gives response message OK. and then I have to it again to execute the query. I don't know what I have done. Is there any way that I can execute the query with a single click

Comment: What version of MySQL Workbench do you use? If not the latest, try the that.

Comment: I use version 6.1.7.11891 built 1788. that's the latest version..